# Unity real time soft shadow

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, shadow, lighting

Trying to implement **real time smooth soft shadow**(see image1) in unity. But default unity shadows seems like not smooth (see image 2). I am new in unity shadow. So is there any other special settings or shader should apply to achieve real time soft shadow like the image1? 
Any suggestion, or  good example or tutorial?

[image: image1]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the quality settings (edit -> project settings -> quality).

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Infodayne, that's the exact thing I was looking for! :)